# 'glyphicon-duplicate' is not rendering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have `Bootstrap v3.3.4`.

`index.html` has `bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`, but `glyphicon-duplicate` does not render. Could anyone tell why?

Comment: I also have this issue. Other icons seem to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I used an alternate way that worked:

```
fa fa-clone
```

Comment: `clone` is not the same icon as `duplicate`. In this particular case, one should use `fa fa-copy` instead of `glyphicon-duplicate`. Other similar icons: `page-copy`, some versions of `copy`, `copy-3`, `ios-copy`, `content-copy`. For future reference, to easily find alternatives, use [GlyphSearch](https://glyphsearch.com/?query=copy-).

Answer (score 0):

At least for my case using Meteor, I found that the popular `mizzao:bootstrap-3` lacks the duplicate icon. To solve the problem, I installed the officially supported package instead:

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

See their [GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) for details

Comment: Well I added `"bootstrap": "latest"` in bower.json and it downloaded `bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`. The js file was `bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`. Are they not officially supported?